# Probability density function (PDF) of a scaled non-central chi squared distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I know that:

1. If $X$ is exponentially distributed with a rate parameter $\lambda$, then $cX$ is exponentially distributed with a rate parameter $\frac{\lambda}{c}$.
2. If $X$ is central chi-squared distributed with $\nu$ degree of freedom, then $cX$ is gamma distributed with shape $\frac{\nu}{2}$ and scale parameter $2c$.

where $c$ is a positive constant.
My question is:

If $X$ is non-central chi-squared distributed with $\nu$ degree of freedom, then how is $cX$ distributed? What is the pdf of $cX$ ?

Comment: In general, the PDF of $cX$ is $\frac{1}{c} f_X(t/c)$ where $f_X$ is the PDF of $X$. I don't know of a nice name for the distribution of your particular $cX$ though.

Comment: Thank you @angryavian. The information you gave is very helpful. By the way, is there a reference where the PDF of $cX$ is $\frac{1}{c}f_X(\frac{t}{c}) $?

Comment: This is a special case of [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables).